# сжатие двумерного массива

Tags: php

Подскажите, какой наилучший способ существует для сжатия 2мерного массива ? Результат сжатия, т.е. строка, должна быть помещена в ячейку с типом `TEXT` в базе данных

`serialize & gzcompress` ?

Посоветуйте мб как лучше

Comment: вопрос поставлен не корректно. Одно переводит массивы и объекты в удобную для хранения и передачи форму (с магией для объектов), другое существует для сжатия больших объёмов до малых.

Comment: @Kirill, что по Вашему в вопросе является некорректным ? Я не просил объяснить мне принцип работы сериализации или компрессии, а попросил посоветовать то, чем можно это заменить. Использую сейчас это и никаких проблем не возникает. Мучают лишь сомнения насчет адекватности подобной схемы.